# Disable listview item in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am trying to disable item (row) in my list view but its seem there no option like .enable = false and I tried to find anything to get my item to by disable but visible. Is there anything like that? If the user is allowed to select it then the item is enabled else it's visible but not enabled.

I have a table in the database that admin will fill it in which the user can view the window or not, so I want the user to able to see it and if not allowed to view it then its disable.

Comment: There is no such thing, but the LV is possibly the most often customized/extended control.  You can find many version, some of which may support disabled items.  The LV is ill suited for that kind of thing anyway - you can do the same with the DGV and just use Views to make things visible or not.

Comment: Can you not just handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event and deselect the selected item, i.e. `Clear` the `SelectedItems` collection, if it is one that you want "disabled"?

Comment: In fact, if you just keep a list of "disabled" items, you can simply loop through that list in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler and set the `Selected` property of each to `False`. That will handle multi-select and single-select scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only works if MultiSelect is set to False and the .Tag property is set for every item. (Yes or No).

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If Not ListView1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            Dim item As ListViewItem = ListView1.SelectedItems(0)
            If item.Tag.ToString = "No" Then
                item.Selected = False
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

As per @ jmcilhinney , The following code should work with MultiSelect = True. I tried to access the last item added to the collection but it seems that the SelectedItems collection is ordered the same as the order the items appear in the ListView; not as expected the last item added would be last in the collection..

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If Not ListView1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
                If item.Tag.ToString = "No" Then
                    item.Selected = False
                End If
            Next
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It will work with `MultiSelect` set to `True` if you loop over the `Items` or `SelectedItems` and use the `Tag` of each one, rather than just the first one in `SelectedItems`. You could even just test the last item in `SelectedItems` because that will be the item just selected.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I added code to work with MultiSelect as you described but had trouble accessing last item added as I explained in my edit. Thank you for the improvement.

Comment: The last item is the one with the last index: `ListView1.SelectedItems(ListView1.SelectedItems.Count - 1)`. Alternatively, use the `Last` extension method: `ListView1.SelectedItems.Cast(Of ListViewItem)().Last()`.  In fact, you can also use `LastOrDefault` and and test that for `Nothing` to do away with your original `If` statement.

Comment: Tried `ListView1.SelectedItems(ListView1.SelectedItems.Count - 1)`First but the collection is not ordered that way. It is ordered the same as Items Collection. Will try .Last

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I didn't realise that.  I tested and it seemed to be the way I assumed but I obviously didn't do enough tests to see that that was only coincidence.

Comment: so can i change the tag in run time so if i put tag= no can i change it to yes if the user has the authorization to use it

Comment: Yes, the tag property can be set at runtime. Don't forget the quotes around "No". The tag property takes any type of object so you have to use the .ToString to check the value.